# Internal error: Unable to map submodel to full model

Tags: statistics, spatstat

I sometimes get this error while running an anova.mppm after fitting mppm models, but then I also get the anova table output along with it, which looks fine. I am wondering if it is okay to use the anova results for my analyses even if I get this error.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. It makes it a lot easier to understand where the error message comes from.

Comment: Here is an example which produces the same error: 

`Str <- hyperframe(str=with(simba, Strauss(mean(nndist(Points)))));  

fit0 <- mppm(Points ~ id, simba);  

fit1 <- mppm(Points ~ id, simba, interaction=Str, iformula = ~str + str:group);  

anova(fit0, fit1, test="Chi")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check that you are using the current releases of the `spatstat` packages.

This type of error occurred with previous versions of `spatstat` but was fixed in `spatstat.core 2.4-1`.

I cannot reproduce this error using the current release of `spatstat.core` (2.4-2).

In case you still get this error after installing the latest releases, there could be a problem with the R installation. Then I suggest you start R and type `library(spatstat); sessionLibs()` to see which versions are actually loaded.